# Autenticação de usuário com banco H2 em Aplicação Kotlin Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin

Problema:
Autenticar usuário usando o banco de dados H2 no Spring Security

Contexto:
A aplicação é feita utilizando Spring, a classe do usuário é esta

```
@Entity
data class Usuario(
        @NotEmpty
        var nome:String = "",
        @NotEmpty
        var login:String = "",
        @NotEmpty
        var senha:String = "",
        @OneToMany(cascade= arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), mappedBy="usuario")
        var simulacoes:MutableSet<Simulacao> = mutableSetOf(),
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id:Int  = 0
)
```

Repositório da classe :

```
interface UsuarioRep:JpaRepository<Usuario,Int>{
    fun findByLogin(login:String):Usuario
}
```

Configuração do SpringSecurity:

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity): Unit {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/cadastro").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/principal").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/");
    }

    @Autowired
    fun configAuthentication(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder){
        //
    }
}
```

Passei algumas horas pesquisando e sem sucesso, a documentação oficial é em java e os tutorias também são escassos.

Pelo o que entendi devo criar um `UserDetailsService`, porém como isso pode ser feito em kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido utilizando a autenticação por `JDBC`

As queries são provisórias enquanto as devidas modificações não são feitas no banco de dados

```
@Autowired
fun configAuthentication(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder){
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username , password, 'true' as enabled from USUARIO where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,role from USUARIO where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder())
}
```

A primeira precisa buscar o parâmetro de nome de usuário (no caso `username`), a senha( definida como `password`), e a o status 'enabled' (no caso provisoriamente sempre verdadeiro).

A segunda precisa buscar o nome de usuário e a role.